# Scala/Play how to update main.scala.html HTML to show/hide text

Tags: javascript, html, scala, playframework

I am new to Scala and Play and am using the main.scala.html page -- which in my understanding, is used as a Single Page Application (SPA) framework.  I hope this is a correct statement.

I am attempting to switch a link/text from Login to Logout, based on a session variable that is set with the application.  For some reason, the main.scala.html page will not recognize this variable, even though it has changed.

Here is the main.scala.html code excerpts:

```
@(user: User = null, scripts: Html = Html(""), isLoggedIn: String = "")(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
...
        <script type="text/javascript">
            @isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn();
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
...
<div class="pull-right">
                        <nav class="navmenu center">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/signup">Register</a></li>
                                @if(isLoggedIn == true) {
                                    <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                                } else {
                                    <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/auth">Login</a></li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
</div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the isLoggedIn() function:
function isLoggedIn() {

```
var email = '<%= Session["email"] %>';
if (email != null || email != "") {
return true;
}
else {
 return false;
}
}
```

I know the email session variable is set -- it is not null, so the code should work.

Is there some sort of "refresh" issue with the main.scala.html?  Or does Scala not function as a SPA framework?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!
Dan

Answer (score 0):

In the template declaration you declared `isLoggedIn` as String. But you are trying to use it as boolean in the if expression.

Also your if condition is wrong. Show login when `isLoggedIn` is true.

```
@if(isLoggedIn) {
    <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/auth">Login</a></li>
} else {
   <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
}
```

Comment: Made the changes to process a String - still will not recognize the variable.    I am guessing there is something with the main.scala.html not being updated when displaying a new <form> inside that .html page.  It seems like the Javascript is not "firing".

Comment: Seems like the line of code -- var email = '<%= Session["email"] %>'; -- returns the value '<%= Session["email"] %>', not the value of the variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

The play templates are not by default SPA. You could make them so by adding in AngularJS or your favorite JavaScript SPA framework. Everything beginning with @ is evaluated (and substituted) on the server side once, when the page is served. So your JavaScript statement `@isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn();`, if you inspect it in your browser, may looking something like `true = isLoggedIn();` or even `= isLoggedIn();` (if for example, the isLoggedIn variable happens to be blank).

If, as @pamu suggests, you change it to a boolean, rather than a string, then your template code can do a once-off check (the evaluation/substitution only happens once) to generate along the lines suggested.

If you want something more dynamic, i.e. don't want to have to load the whole page in order to make that change, then you will have to look to JavaScript and an SPA framework on the front-end.